# How to identify network drive path inside lotus notes forms

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, hcl-notes

We have existing lotus notes applications. How to identify network path in that lotus notes form which is already developed? we installed lotus notes designer and we opened the lotus notes .nsf file. we are not aware how to identify the network drive path which contains txt files as source for this lotus notes forms.

Comment: I think there is a very basic misunderstanding on how Notes / Domino works: There are not "network drive paths" or the like that contain text files... 

Notes / Domino is a document based database system: All the data is stored within the .nsf files in "Documents". These documents may or may not be based on forms that you examine in Domino Designer and are usually shown in views. 

You see: My answer is totally different from the (absolutely correct one) of Richard... 

Please make it clearer what you want to know, because like this your question can not be answered.

Comment: As also shown in your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78063977/ , you are lacking the basic knowledge and understanding of Notes/Domino application development. The product includes very good documentation for the basics (database/view/form, ...). Please work through that first and get some formal training, as this will help you resolving your tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'm going to say is that it's pretty unusual for Notes code to refer to a network drive path. Modern operating systems tend to be locked down pretty tightly, and a Domino server should probably not be running with permissions to reach out across network drives.

That said, you should probably use the Database Synopsis feature, and select Forms, subforms, and Script Libraries. Then search the generated synopsis (I usually copy from the output window and paste it into a text editor). The first thing I'd do is search for the word "path", because programmers are usually not very creative with their names for variables. If that fails, I would search for "file", and "open", or things like "C:", "D:", etc.   IIRC, UNC paths (e.g., "\sharename\folder\file") do not work in Notes/Domino.If all that searching fails to turn up what you want, I would read through all the code.